# How can I pass id of individual dynamically created elements by clicking on submit button to a function - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

First look at my code, then at bottom i asked the question.

Here is my HTML -

```
<form action="confirm_booking.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" value="26-March-2014" name="event_date">
<select id="seltimeslot-26-March-2014" class="seltime" name="seltimeslot">
<option value="null">Select a Time</option>
<option disabled="disabled" value="1">9am-10am - Taken</option>
<option value="2">10am-11am - Available</option>
<option disabled="disabled" value="3">11am-12pm - Taken</option>
<option value="4">12pm-1pm - Available</option>
<option value="5">1pm-2pm - Available</option>
<option value="6">2pm-3pm - Available</option>
<option value="7">3pm-4pm - Available</option>
<option value="8">4pm-5pm - Available</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="return checkForm();" value="Book Slot" name="btnbook">
</form>



<form action="confirm_booking.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" value="27-March-2014" name="event_date">
<select id="seltimeslot-27-March-2014" class="seltime" name="seltimeslot">
<option value="null">Select a Time</option>
<option value="1">9am-10am - Available</option>
<option value="2">10am-11am - Available</option>
<option value="3">11am-12pm - Available</option>
<option value="4">12pm-1pm - Available</option>
<option disabled="disabled" value="5">1pm-2pm - Taken</option>
<option value="6">2pm-3pm - Available</option>
<option value="7">3pm-4pm - Available</option>
<option value="8">4pm-5pm - Available</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="return checkForm();" value="Book Slot" name="btnbook">
</form>
```

Note that the above HTML is dynamically generated through the mysql query and PHP loop. It is for each day of a month.

Now for validation to check whether the user has selected a value from the select list box when the corresponding submit button is clicked, i have the following JavaScript function -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(id)
{
    var time_slot = document.getElementById(id);
    if(time_slot.value == "null")
    {
        alert("Please select your available event time slot.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Now please tell me how can i pass the individual select list box element id to this function by clicking on its corresponding submit button? Suppose if submit button for the select list box with id seltimeslot-26-March-2014 is pressed then it will check the validation only for the corresponding select list box with id seltimeslot-26-March-2014 and not for others. If user has selected a value of select list box with id seltimeslot-27-March-2014 and press the submit button of seltimeslot-26-March-2014 then the alert must say - "please select your available event time slot" because he is not pressing the submit button for the select list box whose value is selected.

Comment: You have a hidden input with the date, once you have the form being submitted (event `onSubmit` in the form instead the `onclick` in the button) you can get that value  to create the needed id

Comment: Please dont go with hidden input field. I am not asking for getting the value of select list box by PHP. Like we use this.id to pass the id of current element, i want to get the id of select list whose corresponding submit button is clicked by the user.

Comment: It seems I did not explain it properly, so I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you look at this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/KwrLp/)

I updated the HTML a bit and used jQuery.  As part of button click I am sending the ID of the Select element

```
function checkForm(id) {
    var time_slot = $('#'+id).val();
    if (time_slot == "null") {
        alert("Please select your available event time slot.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

There is another way of doing this, but this is with the least changes I can think of.

Following fiddle is another way I was talking about: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/Lsbjc/)

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="btnbook"]').on('click', function (ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
        $event = $(ev.target);
        $closestSelect = $event.parent().children('select');
        var time_slot = $closestSelect.val();
        if (time_slot == "null") {
            alert("Please select your available event time slot.");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("You selected a value: " + time_slot);
            return true;
        } 
    });
});
```

I updated the html to remove the onclick event.  Let me know if this is not what you were looking for or have some other issues.

Comment: i checked it on jsFiddle and though your code is working good but there is still a problem - you have written static select list box id i.e. onclick="return checkForm('seltimeslot-27-March-2014');" I already told these html are coming dynamically in a loop so we cant write it as. I also told like we send current element id by doing this.id, so can we send the id of other element whose submit button is clicked. I mean to say that what need to be passed in the parentheses of  checkForm();?

Comment: Why can't you add the id in the same way you set the value of the hidden field? As far as I understand it's also created dynamically

Comment: @user3185166: I just updated the response with jQuery updates.  Look at the new Fiddle and let me know if that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: Now I have got it clearly. Actually I was thinking in some other way that had confused me. In fact it could be a small and easy workaround for me. You wrote correctly in your function checkForm(id) {
    var time_slot = $('#'+id).val();. I did the same but just use of vanilla JavaScript function checkForm(id)
{
 var seltimeslot = document.getElementById(id);
 and in HTML i have now <input type='submit' name='btnbook' value='Book Slot' $disable onclick='return checkForm(\"seltimeslot-$event_date\");' />.

Comment: Thus the dynamic Id of select list boxes are coming in the parameter of checkForm() function and all is done. But nevertheless thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have a hidden input with the date, once you have the form submitted you can get that value  of that input and use it to create the id:

```
//this is window
//this.event.currentTarget is the button
//this.event.currentTarget.parentElement.event_date is the hidden field

function checkForm() {
    var id='#seltimeslot-'+this.event.currentTarget.parentElement.event_date.value;
    console.log (id);
    console.log($(id).val());
    if ($(id).val() == "null") {
        alert("Please select your available event time slot.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Of course this just answers what you asked, but you can directly use
that approach to check directly the selected element:

```
function checkForm() {

    if (this.event.currentTarget.parentElement.seltimeslot.value == "null") {
        alert("Please select your available event time slot.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
You cannot use

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return checkForm(this.id);" value="Book Slot" name="btnbook">
```

because `this` in runtime is `window`

Comment: So do you think I don't need to pass any parameter in the function call i.e. from <input type="submit" onclick="return checkForm();" value="Book Slot" name="btnbook"> ? I think if we can send corresponding select list box id then we can grab its value in the function. Like we use checkForm(this.id) and it can send the submit button id to the function, in the same what if we can send the id of corresponding select list box? How do I do that? What do you think?